# Redux Toolkit :Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

With this code, I get no errors.

```js
import {combineReducers, configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {menuReducer as menu} from './menu';
import {cartReducer as cart} from './shoppingCart';
import {optionsReducer as options} from './optionsItem';
import {homeReducer as home} from './home';
import {rewardReducer as reward} from './reward';
import {ordersReducer as orders} from './orders';
import {authReducer as auth} from './auth';
import giftCardReducer from '../store/giftCard';
import paymentMethodReducer from './paymentMethod';
import paymentToken from "./paymentToken";
import qRCode from "./qRCode";
import orderHistory from './orderHistory';
import orderDetail from './orderDetail';
import showCompletedOrder from './showCompletedOrder';
import paymentOptionsSummary from './paymentOptionsSummary';
import usersUpdate from './usersUpdate';
import referAFriend from './referAFriend';
import resetPassword from './resetPassword';

const reducer = combineReducers({
  menu,
  auth,
  giftCardReducer,
  paymentMethodReducer,
  cart,
  options,
  orders,
  home,
  reward,
  paymentToken,
  qRCode,
  orderHistory,
  orderDetail,
  showCompletedOrder,
  paymentOptionsSummary,
  usersUpdate,
  referAFriend,
  resetPassword
});
export {menuActions} from './menu';
export {cartActions} from './shoppingCart';
export {optionsActions} from './optionsItem';
export {ordersActions} from './orders';
export {authActions} from './auth';
export {homeActions} from './home';
export {rewardActions} from './reward';

export type rootState = ReturnType<typeof reducer>;

export default configureStore({
  reducer:reducer
});


const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'auth/logout') { // check for action type 
    state = undefined;
  }
  return reducer(state, action);
};
```

If I change this to the code below, I get the error mentioned.

```js
import {combineReducers, configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {menuReducer as menu} from './menu';
import {cartReducer as cart} from './shoppingCart';
import {optionsReducer as options} from './optionsItem';
import {homeReducer as home} from './home';
import {rewardReducer as reward} from './reward';
import {ordersReducer as orders} from './orders';
import {authReducer as auth} from './auth';
import giftCardReducer from '../store/giftCard';
import paymentMethodReducer from './paymentMethod';
import paymentToken from "./paymentToken";
import qRCode from "./qRCode";
import orderHistory from './orderHistory';
import orderDetail from './orderDetail';
import showCompletedOrder from './showCompletedOrder';
import paymentOptionsSummary from './paymentOptionsSummary';
import usersUpdate from './usersUpdate';
import referAFriend from './referAFriend';
import resetPassword from './resetPassword';

const reducer = combineReducers({
  menu,
  auth,
  giftCardReducer,
  paymentMethodReducer,
  cart,
  options,
  orders,
  home,
  reward,
  paymentToken,
  qRCode,
  orderHistory,
  orderDetail,
  showCompletedOrder,
  paymentOptionsSummary,
  usersUpdate,
  referAFriend,
  resetPassword
});
export {menuActions} from './menu';
export {cartActions} from './shoppingCart';
export {optionsActions} from './optionsItem';
export {ordersActions} from './orders';
export {authActions} from './auth';
export {homeActions} from './home';
export {rewardActions} from './reward';

export type rootState = ReturnType<typeof reducer>;

export default configureStore({
  reducer:rootReducer
});


const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'auth/logout') { // check for action type 
    state = undefined;
  }
  return reducer(state, action);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I got the solution.

This error is shows because i have put the `rootReducer` function below the configure store that's why reducer id not getting the `rootReducer` function.

So, when I move it up then its working fine.

Answer (score 9):

I also had this problem in React when I configured my redux store inside my client index.js file. This was my code that produces the error:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import allReducers from "./redux/reducer";

const store = configureStore({ allReducers });

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**QUICK FIX:** As the error suggests, `"reducer" is a required argument...` So, I just modified my store constant like so: `configureStore({reducer: allReducers})`. I just made "reducer" as a key, and passed `allReducers` as its value. My problem is then fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Try this way

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
const reducer = combineReducers({
  // here we will be adding reducers
})
const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
})
export default store;
```

Details [Here](https://www.softkraft.co/how-to-setup-redux-with-redux-toolkit/#how-to-setup-create-react-app-with-redux)

Comment: Yep this worker in my case. Well I tried multiple things but your solution was only the one which worked. I was directly using "const dispatch=useDispatch()" but this somehow caused white screen with errors saying "useReduxContext.js:24 Uncaught Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>" but even after I provided the proper wrapping up like this <Provider/> <App/> <Provider/> I was getting blank screen with error saying ". Then I went ahead to include your piece of code inside my index.js file and it suddenly started working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In case if you still have error then do this

```js
const store = configureStore({reducer:reducers})
```

here `reducers` is variable that contains your combined reducers.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `configureStore` neatly articulates the various options that can be passed in by keyword within the config object that a few of the others have alluded to.

If you are still struggling with this error, be sure to check the documentation [here.](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore) It is very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

My solution was:

```js
 const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    users: reducer
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

canceled braces and change `configureStore` to `createStore`

Comment: Question is about configureStore(), not createStore().